# Flutter's sqflite queries

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I am working with an already existing database `dictionary.db` that has a table `words` and has 4 columns `id`, `englishWord`, `germanWord`, `isFavorite`.

Using Sqflite I am trying to return a list of German words based on an input in English pretty much the userflow works like this: user input an English word (example: "Ability") and I return a list of synonyms to that word in German.

My problem is I don't know how to do it the method I am trying returns the full list instead of only the intended search results

This is my Entity:

```
class Word {
  final String id;
  final String eng;
  final String ger;
  final String isFav;

  Word({this.id, this.eng, this.ger, this.isFav});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'wordId': id,
      'englishWord': eng,
      'germanWord': ger,
      'isFavorite': isFav, 
    };
  }

  factory Word.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Word(
    id: json['wordId'],
    eng: json['englishWord'],
    ger: json['germanWord'],
    isFav: json['isFavorite']
  );
}
```

And this is my database helper class:

```
class DatabaseHelper{
  DatabaseHelper._();
  static final DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper._();
  Database _database;

  static const String DB_NAME = "dict.db";
  static const String TABLE = "words";
  static const String ID = "wordId";
  static const String ENGLISH_WORD = "englishWord";
  static const String GERMAN_WORD = "germanWord";
  static const String IS_FAV = "isFavorite";

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await getDatabaseInstance();
    return _database;
  }

  Future<Database> getDatabaseInstance() async {
    io.Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(directory.path, DB_NAME);
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $TABLE ("
          "$ID TEXT,"
          "$ENGLISH_WORD TEXT,"
          "$GERMAN_WORD TEXT,"
          "$IS_FAV TEXT"
          ")");
    });
  }

  //This is where I get the search result list
  //I am stuck here I don't know where to go from here, I only get the full list
  Future<List<Word>> searchEnglishResults(String userSearch) async{
    final db = await database;
    var response = await db.query("Word");
    List<Word> list = response.map((c) => Word.fromMap(c)).toList();
    return list;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed the database is like below:

```
|id     | englidhWord | germanWord        | isFavorite |
|-------|-------------|-------------------|------------|
| 'id0' | 'bye'       | 'Tschüss'         | 'false'    |
| 'id1' | 'bye'       | 'Auf Wiedersehen' | 'true'     |
```

so if the user searches for "bye", she/he should receive [ 'Tschüss', 'Auf Wiedersehen'](the Word model not only the German words).

For that, `query` has some options like `where` and `whereArgs` that you can use to search for a specific row on the database.

Here we want to search the database for rows that their `englidhWord` field has a value of `bye`.

Here is the edited version of your DB:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sudoku/src/word.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  DatabaseHelper._();
  static final DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper._();
  Database _database;

  String DB_NAME = "dict.db";
  static const String TABLE = "words";
  static const String ID = "wordId";
  static const String ENGLISH_WORD = "englishWord";
  static const String GERMAN_WORD = "germanWord";
  static const String IS_FAV = "isFavorite";

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await getDatabaseInstance();
    return _database;
  }

  Future<Database> getDatabaseInstance() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(directory.path, DB_NAME);
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $TABLE ("
          "$ID TEXT,"
          "$ENGLISH_WORD TEXT,"
          "$GERMAN_WORD TEXT,"
          "$IS_FAV TEXT"
          ")");
    });
  }
   //add new words
   Future<int> add(Word word) async {
    final db = await database;
    var response = await db.insert(TABLE, word.toMap());

    return response;
  }

  //This is where I get the search result list
  //I am stuck here I don't know where to go from here, I only get the full list
  Future<List<Word>> searchEnglishResults(String userSearch) async {
    final db = await database;
    var response = await db
        .query(TABLE, where: '$ENGLISH_WORD = ?', whereArgs: [userSearch]);
    List<Word> list = response.map((c) => Word.fromMap(c)).toList();
    return list;
  }
}
```

And I show the result with listview on a page named `MyApp`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sudoku/src/db.dart';
import 'package:sudoku/src/word.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  DatabaseHelper db;
  @override
  void initState() {
    db = DatabaseHelper.databaseHelper;
    add();
    super.initState();
  }

  add() async {
    // await db.add(Word(eng: 'hi', ger: 'Hallo', id: 'id2', isFav: 'true'));
    // await db.add(Word(eng: 'bye', ger: 'Tschüss', id: 'id0', isFav: 'fasle'));
    // await db.add(
    //     Word(eng: 'bye', ger: 'Auf Wiedersehen', id: 'id0', isFav: 'true'));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Word>>(
        future: db.searchEnglishResults('bye'),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Word>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData)
            return ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(snapshot.data[index].ger),
                  subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].eng),
                  trailing: Text(snapshot.data[index].isFav),
                );
              },
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            );

          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I included a function named "add" in database and MyApp's initState to add new words to database.

If you refresh app for multiple time, it will add repetitive rows, the reason is that you should make one of the DB field unique, here can be `id` to do so you should create the table like below:

```dart
return await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $TABLE ("
          "$ID TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
          "$ENGLISH_WORD TEXT,"
          "$GERMAN_WORD TEXT,"
          "$IS_FAV TEXT"
          ")");
    });
```

Also in `add` function in DB, you should choose what should be done when it faces to a repetitive row(Word here), there are some options, one can be to replace it, it should change like this:

```dart
  //add new words
  Future<int> add(Word word) async {
    final db = await database;
    var response = await db.insert(TABLE, word.toMap(), conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);

    return response;
  }
```

I hope it was what You were looking for.

Comment: That was super helpful! a quick question tho, can use a query that searches everything at once? Something like this: `var response = await db.query (TABLE, where: "$ENGLISH_WORD or $GERMAN_WORD = ?", whereArgs: [ENGLISH_WORD, GERMAN_WORD]);`

Comment: Happy that it helped. Yes, you can use almost all sorts of these queries, even things like [joins](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-inner-join/) are available, also things like foreign key are available. there is also a `raw` version of these functions for more complicated queries. (`rawQuery`)

Comment: so the queryI wrote in the comment is correct ? And doesn't need any tweaking ?

Comment: Yes, it's correct, this will search for rows that one of the conditions is correct, the correct form is ` "$ENGLISH_WORD = ? or $GERMAN_WORD = ?"  `